# s3 never-ending pending audio requests

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an mp3 file on s3 (and have experienced with many other mp3 files) that is not playing in chrome (and other browsers as well: FF, safari, etc).  The network dialog in chrome shows that there is a pending request that is seemingly never responded to by s3, however if I do a wget to the URL, I get an immediate response.

Additionally, if I serve the exact same file off of a server running nginx, I can access the URL in chrome as well instantaneously.  I know that S3 does support byte range requests, so there should be no issue with chrome's byte range queries.  Additionally, I've verified that the file is accessible, and that its content type is audio/mpeg.

Here is the file in question:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/josh-tmdbucket/23/talks/ffcc525a0761cd9e7023ab51c81edb781077377d.mp3

Here is a screenshot of the network requests in chrome for that URL:[image]

Comment: Did you figure what was causing this?

Comment: No, and I left the project so I'm not sure how they resolved this

Comment: I figured my pending error.  It was due to an infinite loop in my javascript for some other code.    Could be that that loop was taking all the cycles and hence causing the GET pending requests

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a **[CloudFront](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home?region=ap-southeast-1) distribution**. You need to create a **distribution** for your **bucket**. For example if you have a bucket named `example-bucket`, go to **CloudFront** and click on **create distribution**. Your bucket will appear in **Origin Domain Name** as `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`

Now you can use `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` url to load content.
This worked for me but I am not sure if it will work for others.

Answer (score 0):

Had same exact issue with files.

```
    Original url looked like this => 
    https://my-bucket-name.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/EIR.mp4
```

Added CloudFront distribution and it solved all my issues.

```
    Url changed only a bit:
    https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/EIR.mp4
```

(but you can modify it a little while creating [distribution](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home?region=ap-southeast-1#distributions:) / even setting your own DNS if you wish).